# Exception where $L^2$-Holder condition does not hold

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Recently, I have tried to resolve the following problem.

Let periodic $f$ be defined by the following Fourier series,
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} e^{ikx}.
\end{align}
Prove that $f$ belongs to Nikol'skii space $H^1_2(-\pi,\pi)$ but
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \vert f(x+h) - f(x) \vert^2 dx \geq \frac{4h^2}{\pi^2}\log \frac{\pi}{\vert h \vert}
\end{align}
for $0<\vert h \vert <1$. It is not that hard to prove the first claim, since $f$ is absolutely convergent, $f\in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$; hence, we can integrate the series term by term. This yields that
\begin{align}
c_n(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-ix(n-k)}}{k^{3/2}}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ix(n-k)} dx = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
\end{align}
if $n=k$. That is, $c_n(f)=0$ for $n\leq0$. Thus, we have for all $0\leq j \in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{2^j\leq \vert n \vert < 2^{j+1}} \vert n \vert^2 \vert c_n(f) \vert^2 = \sum_{2^j\leq  n < 2^{j+1}} \frac{n^2}{n^3} \leq 2^j2^{-j}< \infty,
\end{align}
which implies that $f\in H^1_2(-\pi,\pi)$. For any $0<\alpha<1$, $f\in H^\alpha_2(-\pi,\pi)$ is equivalent to $L^2$-Holder condition with $\alpha$. But $\alpha=1$ in this case, so I have tried to get a certain lower bound of the following with sufficiently small $\vert h \vert$. Using Parseval equality,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \vert f(x+h) - f(x) \vert^2 dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\vert e^{inh}-1 \vert^2}{n^3} = 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(nh/2)}{n^3}\geq \frac{4h^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^3}
\end{align}
where $N$ satisfying $0<\vert h \vert < N\vert h \vert < \pi$ since $\vert \sin(nh/2) \vert \geq \vert h \vert / \pi$ for all $1\leq n\leq N$. After getting this far, I stopped for a bit. How can we derive the logarithmic term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have fully resolved the OP. It was my simple mistake.

Since $\vert \sin(nh/2) \vert \geq (2/\pi)(n\vert h\vert /2)$ for all $n$ satisfying $n\vert h \vert \leq \pi$ due to the concavity of $\sin(z)$ on $z\in[0,\pi/2]$, then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \vert f(x+h) - f(x) \vert^2 dx \geq \frac{4h^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\vert h \vert \leq \pi} \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}

There is $0<N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $N \vert h \vert \leq \pi < (N+1)\vert h \vert$ by Archimedean property, and using Riemann-sum implies that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} \geq \log(N+1) \geq \log\frac{\pi}{\vert h \vert},
\end{align}
for all $N>0$ since $1/n$ is monotonic decreasing. This concludes the proof.